# How does flutter handle mobile screen being turned off?

Tags: flutter, dart

Only some Dart code runs when the screen is off. What does Flutter do when the mobile phone screen is turned off? Does it stop rendering but still runs specific Dart code?

---

In my case, Dart callback functions (passed to Flutter plugins) are called even when the screen is off. I want to customise/ control this behaviour, as I am running computational costly code that shouldn't run when the user can't see the output. I can already run code when the screen is turned off (such as by using screen_state flutter plugin or using `ScreenStateObserver` as provided by Miguel Ruivo, but it has limitations. I am not able to pop the route using `Navigator.pop()`. I also want to generally understand how Flutter is affected when the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) mixin as it will provide you with the different application lifecycle to your widget's state.

You'll then want to subscribe on `initState()`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }
```

and remove the listener on `dispose()`

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and access the different states on `didChangeAppLifecycleState()`

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('app resumed');
        break;
      
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('app inactive');
        break;
      
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('app paused');
        break;
    
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print('app deatched');
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good option instead of using [screen_state](https://pub.dev/packages?q=screen_state). But why does some code not run when the screen is off in Flutter: e.g. why does `Navigator.pop` not actually pop the route immediately when inside switch statement you provided?.